# ModelState.AddModelError and @Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, validation, actionlink, modelstate

Is it possible to validate a `@Html.ActionLink` with `ModelState.AddModelError`? Within my project I'm trying guide the user to add additional information to their profile. When the user logs in to edit their profile I want to prompt the user with a Validation error if the user has not filled out the form for billing address.

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(UserProfile model)
    {
        if (model.Address == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "please enter in a address");
        }
        model.Address = db.Addresses.SingleOrDefault(a => a.AddressId == model.AddressId);
```

Model

```
[Display(Name = "Address")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "please enter in a billing address")]
public Nullable<int> AddressId { get; set; }
```

View

```
if (Model.Address == null)
{
    <br/>

    @Html.ActionLink("Add a billing address", "Create", "Address", new { returnUrl = "UserProfile/Edit", userId = Model.UserId }, null)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Address)
}
else
{
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Address.Line1)<br />
        @if (Model.Address.Line2 != null)
        {
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Address.Line2)<br />
        }
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Address.City), @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Address.State.Abbreviation) @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Address.PostalCode)
    </div>

    @Html.ActionLink("Edit address", "Edit", "Address", new { id = Model.AddressId, returnUrl = "UserProfile/Edit", userId = Model.UserId }, null)
}
```

Comment: Your logic does not make sense. If the address is required, why is it not part of the initial form and its properties decorated with the `[Required]` attribute. If its not but you just want to prompt the user to add it, then adding a `ModelStateError` is not appropriate - just add a message to a view model or `ViewBag` property and display t in the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `ModelState` in the view.

```
@model ModelWithAddress

@{
    var address = ViewContext.ViewData.ModelState["Address"];
}

@if (address != null && address.Errors.Count() > 0)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Add a billing address", "Create", "Address",
        new { returnUrl = "UserProfile/Edit", userId = Model.UserId }, null)
}
```